# Calculating risk of contracting HIV from a single exposure

Tags: statistics

If the risk of contracting HIV by insertive vaginal sex is 1 in 2500 acts (if the female is HIV positive) and 0.3% of the population have the virus.

How can we calculate the chance of getting infected from a single exposure considering both the 0.3% and the 1 in 2500?

Comment: If you ask this cause you are scared, well that's $0$. Otherwise someone will give you a "correct" answer, which is basically $0$ tho.

Comment: No I'm not scared. I just want to know how to calculate it. I'm not concerned with anything

Comment: Just multiply $3/1000$ and $1/2500$ which is $0,0000012$ ie $0,00012$%.